# Paging in jTemplates

Tags: jquery, jtemplates

I am using jTemplates on PHP page. Is there any paging feature in jTemplates? Or Do I need to do it myself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the work, but a guideline is already available [at this site](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=610).

In this example the server code to retrieve data is in .Net but since you already have a php page you should just understand and adapt HTML and javascript code.